# Postgresql version in docker container is not compatible with its data

Tags: postgresql, docker, version

Mac OS 10.13.6
docker 9.03.5, build 633a0ea

I create two docker containers, web and db using docker-compose.yml. It worked for several months. Recently I decided to rebuild containers from scratch, so I actually removed the existing ones and started over:

```
$ docker-compose  -f docker-compose-dev.yml build --no-cache
$ docker-compose  -f docker-compose-dev.yml up -d
```

Duiring the "build" run, building db container yields this:

> DETAIL:  The data directory was initialised by PostgreSQL version 9.6,
>   which is not compatible with this version 11.2.
>
> exited with code 1

The db container does not start so I can not check what it's got inside.

My containers
 are defined like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: web
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: '<my_app>.settings.postgres'
      DB_NAME: 'my_db'
      DB_USER: 'my_db_user'
      DB_PASS: 'my_db_user'
      DB_HOST: 'my_db_host'
      PRODUCTION: 'false'
      DEBUG: 'True'
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app/
  db:
    image: postgres:11.2-alpine
    volumes:
      - myapp-db-dev:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=<my_db>
      - POSTGRES_USER=<my_db_user>
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<my_db_password>
volumes:
  myapp-db-dev:
```

My local postgresql is 11.3 (which should be irrelevant):

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 11.3
```

and my local postgresql  data directory was removed completely

```
$ rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres
```

However, it's up-to-date:

```
$ brew postgresql-upgrade-database
Error: postgresql data already upgraded!
```

I read [Stack Overflow 17822974](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822974/postgres-fatal-database-files-are-incompatible-with-server) and [Stack Overflow 19076980](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19076980/postgres-versions-are-not-compatible), those advices did not help.

How to fix this data incompatibility? If possible, I would like to avoid downgrading postgres. I don't even get what data it's talking about at that point, all the data is migrated later in a separate step.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like on the first run Postgres 9.6 was specified as an image. So, the container was initialized and the data was put to the `myapp-db-dev` named volume. Then someone changed the version and you've got the error. The possible solution would be:

1. Temporary downgrade the version to the Postgres 9.6, e.g. specify `postgres:9.6`.
2. Go to the container and dump the data with `pg_dump` utility.
3. Change version to 11.2 and specify new volume (it's a good advice to use host volume).
4. Restore the data.

Comment: What's `pg_data` ? Maybe `pg_dump` ? Could you elaborate on "specify new volume" please? Curenty in `db` container of my  `docker-compose.yml` I have `- data:/var/lib/postgresql/data`, should I replace it with something else? With what?

Comment: @SwissNavy yes, it should be `pg_dump`. Yes, for example with `./mydata: /var/lib/postgresql/data`, but check twice that you properly backed up your data.